# Automatic logging to file with Audited gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-audited

Using the Rails Audited gem, I would like to also have a friendly, human readable log file that has all the updates.

Is there a way to easily do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage this option [from the doc](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited#custom-audit-model):

```
class CustomAudit < Audited::Audit
  after_commit :custom_log

  def custom_log
    # do what you need here with attributes
  end
end

# Then set it in an initializer like config/initializers/audited.rb
Audited.config do |config|
  config.audit_class = CustomAudit
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this part of the docs, but this is where things get a little confusing for me. I already have a model `Audit < Audited.audit_class` that defines some `ActiveRelations`, not sure how these two work together.

Comment: I cant tell what you use it for :)

Comment: but the overall logic is unchanged: use your own model as audit_class, then  add a callback to add your logger logic